# Unable to get local issuer certificate when using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

here is my code

```
import requests;
url='that website';
headers={
  'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7',
  'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
};
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers);
print(r);
print(r.status_code);
```

then it ran into this:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.xxxxxx.com', port=44 3):
>
> Max retries exceeded with url: xxxxxxxx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1045)')))

what should i do?

Comment: If you do have certificate, try `r = requests.get(url,headers=headers, cert=("/path/to/file.crt", "/path/to/file.key"))`

Comment: Normally the python installation has access to root certificate authorities. However on some OSes such as OSX, the root CA are empty. Check this answer, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56031239/1617295

Comment: I found this awesome article explaining the cause of it: https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce

Comment: Are/Were you on a Mac by any chance? Check out this answer on how to install certificates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310545/778533

Comment: Here is a [step-by-step tutorial on how to add missing certificates to `certifi` and hence to `Requests`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111417/516699).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**It's not recommended** to use `verify = False` in your organization's environments. This is essentially disabling SSL verification.

Sometimes, when you are behind a company proxy, it replaces the certificate chain with the ones of Proxy. Adding the certificates in cacert.pem used by certifi should solve the issue. I had similar issue. Here is what I did, to resolve the issue -

1. Find the path where cacert.pem is located -

> Install certifi, if you don't have. Command: `pip install certifi`

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
C:\\Users\\[UserID]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi\\cacert.pem
```

2. Open the URL on a browser. Download the chain of certificates from the URL and save as Base64 encoded .cer files.
3. Now open the cacert.pem in a notepad and just add every downloaded certificate contents (`---Begin Certificate--- *** ---End Certificate---`) at the end.

Comment: you recommend to install certifi to find a certificate inside its certifi-folder. can you please explain something about the backgrounds?

Comment: Hello, it looks like Python uses certifi module for SSL communications. This certifi module uses cacert.pem file to validate against the SSL certificate. Only the certificates chains that are stored in cacert.pem are considered valid. When any SSL certificate is not found in this file, causes "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" error.

Comment: All I had to do was `sudo pip install certifi` and that seemed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: @BenDavis Yap, certifi would work as-is without any changes, if the machine is not behind any proxy, like ZScalar.

Comment: If you get the error using urllib's `urlopen`, you can install certifi and then do `urlopen(url, cafile="/path/to/file.pem", capath="/path/to/certifi/").read()`

Comment: So that other don't have to dig to figure out how to do Step 2: [How to download certificates from URL](https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2)

Comment: Step 2 with Chrome on a Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940396/how-to-export-certificate-from-chrome-on-a-mac

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked for FastAPI in Docker

Comment: This worked for me too. Why must everything be a struggle to get the environment ready and working in python!!  :-)

Comment: @FMFF I think because Python Software Foundation is a nonprofit organization

Comment: Even easier to get full certificate chain if you use Mozilla Browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694605/12226311

Comment: What url are you talking about?

Comment: I have a bunch of certificates in my cacert.pem, all looking such as this:

# Issuer: xxx
# Subject: xxx
# Label: "GlobalSign Root CA"
# Serial: 
# MD5 Fingerprint:
# SHA1 Fingerprint: 
# SHA256 Fingerprint: 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxyyyzzz
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
I don't understand what should I do with this file. Do I save it as a .cer and then what?

Comment: Updated instruction on how to download SSL Certificate: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/bus-analyst/field-mobility/learn-how-to-download-a-ssl-certificate-for-a-secured-portal/

Comment: In a new VM that I'm working on, there are several CACERT.PEM files. I had to do this to cacert.pem specifically in F:\SRC\Python\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi

env - being the environment.

Comment: One more note - If you use Visual Studio 2022, anytime I refresh the requirement.txt file, the CACERT.PEM in your env folder gets refreshed too. So I have to repeat this. If anyone knows a work around for this, please share.

Comment: Important for me was as @indranil said to get the CHAIN of certificates. Tried with just the single certificate, fail. With the chain, success.

Comment: I tried the solution still getting the error because the URL has "https" in it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 35):

Answers pointing to `certifi` are a good start and in this case there could be an additional step needed if on Windows.

```
pip install python-certifi-win32
```

The above package would patch the installation to include certificates from the local store without needing to manage store files manually. The patch was suggested to `certifi` but declined as "the purpose of certifi is not to be a cross-platform module to access the system certificate store." [https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/pull/54#issuecomment-288085993]

The issue with local certificates traces to Python TLS/SSL and Windows Schannel. There is an open issue at Python [https://bugs.python.org/issue36011] and PEP that did not lead to a solution [https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0543/#resolution]

Answer (score 34):

If you have already tried to update the CA(root) Certificate using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

or have already downloaded the newest version of cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and replaced the old one in `{Python_Installation_Location}\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi\\cacert.pem` but it still does not work, then your client is probably missing the Intermediate Certificate in the trust chain.

Most browsers can automatically download the Intermediate Certificate using the URL in
"Authority Info Access" section in the Certificate, but Python, Java, and openssl s_client cannot. They rely on the server proactively sending them the intermediate certificate.

[image: Authority Information Access]

If you speak Chinese you can read this awesome [blog](https://www.cnblogs.com/sslwork/p/5986985.html) and use this [tool](https://www.myssl.cn/tools/check-server-cert.html) to check if the intermediate certificate is sent by / installed on the server or not.

If you do not, you can check this [article](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/install-intermediate-certificates-avoid-ssl-tls-not-trusted/).

We can also use openssl in Linux to cross-check this issue:

```
openssl s_client -connect yourwebsite:443
```

[image: openssl: unable to get local issuer certificate]
The error message is even the same -- "unable to get local issuer certificate". I doubt that "local" here actually means "intermediate".

My current solution for this problem is like [Indranil's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57466119/4522434): Export the Intermediate Certificate in browser using base64 X.509 CER format; then use Notepad++ to open it and copy the content into the end of cacert.pem in `{Python_Installation_Location}\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi\\cacert.pem`

Comment: In the result of openssl command, CN = Common name, O = Organization, OU = Organization Unit, L = Locality, C = Country, S = State, ref link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24191_01/common/tutorials/authz_cert_attributes.html

Comment: Useful to know about "Authority Info Access", thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you're using macOS, search for "Install Certificates.command" file (it is usually in Macintosh HD > Applications > your_python_dir).

You can also find it with "command" + "break space" and paste "Install Certificates.command" in the field.

If you used brew to install python, your solution is there:
[brew installation of Python 3.6.1: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649449/brew-installation-of-python-3-6-1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate/44649450#44649450)

Answer (score 5):

In macOS just open Macintosh HD

Now Select Application Then Select Python folder ( Python3.6, Python3.7 Whatever You are using just select this folder )

Then, double click on Install Certificates.command. Now your error should be solved.

Answer (score 5):

For me the solution was quite easy:

1. Download the certificate chain as PEM file. For that, I used Mozilla Firefox, viewed the certificate and clicked on the link "PEM (Chain)", see screenshot.

   [image]
2. Following the [documentation of requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), I added the `verify` parameter, i.e. it looked for me like `requests.post(url, params, verify='/path/to/domain-chain.pem')`, where `domain-chain.pem` is the file, that has been downloaded in step 1. The `get` function has also got the `verify` parameter. It is also possible, when using a session, see the example in the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification).

Then it worked.

Comment: Also if you're on a Linux system with an up-to-date SSL certificate directory you can just use the system certificates with `requests.post(url, params, verify='/etc/ssl/certs')`

Answer (score 4):

You can also set REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE env variable to force requests library to use your cert, that solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was able to make requests against my server via the browser, but using python requests, I was getting the error mentioned above. Requests and certifi were both fully up to date; the problem ended up being my server's configuration.

The problem was that I had only installed the intermediate cert instead of the full cert chain.

In my case, following [this article](https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000460374-Combining-root-and-intermediate-certificates), I simply ran `cat my-domain.crt my-domain.ca-bundle > my-domain.crt-combined` and installed the crt-combined file on my server (via heroku's app settings interface) instead of the `crt` file.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for me (i am on python3.9) is to install with a :

```
python -m pip install pip-system-certs
```

This will import the certificates taking into account your OS

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows machine behind a ZScaler proxy, none of the above solutions worked for me. I had to export and collect all my system certificates into a single PEM, which I made available for Python through the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable. I made the following [PowerShell Core](https://superuser.com/questions/1621460/whats-the-difference-between-powershell-desktop-and-powershell-core) snippet to solve this.

| ⓘ Note |
| --- |
| The original solution assumed [you have `openssl` installed](https://winget.run/pkg/ShiningLight/OpenSSL), but I've updated it to not require. |

```pwsh
function Set-CaCertsBundles
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'Medium')]
    param(
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Environment variable target')]
        [ValidateScript({ $_ -ne [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine -or [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator) }, ErrorMessage = 'Cannot set machine environment variables without admin privileges')]
        [ArgumentCompleter({ [System.Enum]::GetNames([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]) })]
        [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]
        $Target = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator) ? [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine : [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User,
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Output file path')]
        [string]
        $CertOutPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\.certs\all.pem",
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Create separate PEM files to import into Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)')]
        [switch]
        $Wsl,
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Terminate on error')]
        [switch]
        $FailFast
    )
    #Requires -Version 6.0
    begin
    {
        if ($FailFast)
        {
            trap { Write-Error -Exception $_; return }  # Stop on error
        }
        $withOpenSSL = $false
        if (-not(Get-Command -Name openssl.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
        {
            if (Test-Path "$env:ProgramFiles\OpenSSL-Win64\bin")
            {
                $env:PATH += [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator + "$env:ProgramFiles\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"
                $withOpenSSL = $true
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $withOpenSSL = $true  # OpenSSL provides additional preamble on each PEM, which is nice for human-readability
        }
        # Collect the certs from the local machine
        $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\ -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Thumbprint }
        $certItem = (Test-Path -Path $CertOutPath -PathType Leaf) ? (Get-Item -Path $CertOutPath <# Get if exists #>) : (New-Item -Path $CertOutPath -ItemType File -Confirm:$ConfirmPreference -Force  <# Create if not exists #> ) 
        if ($null -eq $certItem -and $WhatIfPreference)
        {
            $certItem = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($CertOutPath)  # For WhatIf, indicates hypothetical output file (not created)
        }
        $envVars = 'GIT_SSL_CAINFO', 'AWS_CA_BUNDLE', 'CURL_CA_BUNDLE', 'NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS', 'REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE', 'SSL_CERT_FILE'
    }
    process
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $certs.Count; $i++)
        {
            Write-Progress -Activity 'Copying certificates' -PercentComplete (100 * $i / $certs.Count)
            if ($withOpenSSL)
            {
                $thumbprintCrt = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "$($certs[$i].Thumbprint).crt"
                if (Test-Path -Path $thumbprintCrt -PathType Leaf)
                {
                    $fs = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($thumbprintCrt, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
                }
                else
                {
                    $fs = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($thumbprintCrt, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create) 
                }
                try
                {
                    $fs.Write($certs[$i].RawData, 0, $certs[$i].RawData.Length)    
                }
                finally
                {
                    $fs.Dispose()
                }
        
                openssl x509 -inform DER -in $thumbprintCrt -text | Add-Content -Path $certItem
                if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 -and $FailFast)
                {
                    Write-Error -Message 'Could not create last pem; stopping script to prevent further errors'
                    return
                }
                Remove-Item -Path $thumbprintCrt
            } else {
                @"
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
$([System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certs[$i].RawData) -replace ".{64}","`$0`n")
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"@ | Add-Content -Path $certItem

            }
        }
    }
    end
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $envVars.Count; $i++)
        {
            Write-Progress -Activity 'Setting environment variables' -Status $envVars[$i] -PercentComplete (100 * $i / $envVars.Count)
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($envVars[$i], "Set environment variable to '$certItem'" ))
            {
                [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($envVars[$i], $certItem.FullName, $Target)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have reproduced this in the [[image: GitHub Logo]Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/79ff3bb9abe542b1a5c2f8a87d361d05).

Comment: OMG! This did it, thanks a lot. Related to this I can't install vscode extensions programmatically, I get cert errors as well, for some reason through the GUI they install fine, example: code --install-extension Angular.ng-template --force

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that the server that I was trying to reach (which I also administrate) had a outdated CA file. When I updated to the correct new one the problem was solved. The point is: maybe is not a problem in your local code, but in the endpoint server.

Answer (score 1):

[This should solve your problem](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/solve-the-dreadful-certificate-issues-in-python-requests-module-2020d922c72f)

This is because the url is a **https** site instead of **http**.
So it requires ssl verification using certificates. If you are working in your firms workstation, internal use sites will be accessible through the browser managed by your organization. The organization will have setup the certificates.

**Atleast these certificates are needed**

- ROOT CA certificate
- Intermediate CA certificate
- Website ( domain ) certificate

The browsers will have these certificates configured, but python will not. So you need to do some manual work to get it working.

As Indranil suggests, using verify=False is not recommended. So download all the certificates as mentioned in the above link and follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error message: **certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate** indicated that no certificates where loaded into the certstore at all. (Python 3.10.6)

On Windows the output of `certifi.where()` pointed to a valid cacert.pem file which 100% included the certificate and following all other suggestions did not fix the issue for me.

`Install Certificates.bat` isn't an option anymore for newer python versions and not verifying certificates is neither a valid solution, nor always possible if you are just running a large application.

Executing the following command prints the file location where open_ssl is looking for the certificates:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.get_default_verify_paths()

DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL/certs')
```

Even though certifi was installed for no apparent reason it's presents wasn't considered. The solution in this case was to create the SSL folder and copy the cacert.pem file from the certifi folder to the mentioned path `C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL/cert.pem`

Comment: I couldn't create the SSL directory due to admin privileges, so I created an environment variable (`"SSL_CERT_FILE"`) and set it to the path returned by `certifi.where()`. Note that I also had to restart my IDE (PyCharm).

Answer (score 0):

Another Way of Fixing This Error:

`settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('SENDER_EMAIL') # email_address
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('SENDER_EMAIL_PASSWORD') # app_password
```

Use below command to install `certifi`:

```
pip install certifi
```

--> my `python` version was `3.8` and certifi version was `2020.11.8`
--> execute below command

Mac user:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.8/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Windows user:

```
C:\your_full_path\Python38\Install Certificates.bat
```