# (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"

Tags: python, rest, api, security, request

I am making an API request, and I've been having issues with the SSL certificate it seems.

`requests.get(url=full_url, headers=headers,verify =certifi.where())`

Gives me the error:

Max retries exceeded with url: ---- (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

I followed the directions here, [Unable to get local issuer certificate when using requests in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python)

and have the updated cert.pem in the location it should be, with the certificates cat at the bottom.

But I am still getting the same error.
For security reasons I do not want to set the verify = False, however that does work. 
Any other way to try and verify this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add all the required certificates in the certificate chain to your cert.pem file ?? All the intermediate certs upto root CA should be part of cert.pem file

Comment: I looked at the certificate path and added the two certificates to the .pem file. Does order matter?

Comment: Can't say for sure but changing the order resolved certificate issues in the past in different context. So you could try

Comment: Yes, reordering them in the .pem didn't work.