# Getting Error unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056) when trying to connect to AWS IoT

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ssl, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I'm getting the following error when trying to connecto t aws IoT

```
    myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py", line 1271, in connect
    return self._AWSIoTMQTTClient.connect(keepAliveIntervalSecond)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py", line 513, in connect
    return self._mqtt_core.connect(keepAliveIntervalSecond)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqtt_core.py", line 196, in connect
    self.connect_async(keep_alive_sec, self._create_blocking_ack_callback(event))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqtt_core.py", line 223, in connect_async
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqtt_core.py", line 211, in connect_async
    rc = self._internal_async_client.connect(keep_alive_sec, ack_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/internal/clients.py", line 122, in connect
    rc = self._paho_client.connect(host, port, keep_alive_sec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/paho/client.py", line 665, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/paho/client.py", line 826, in reconnect
    ciphers=self._tls_ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1222, in wrap_socket
    suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

I have tried several methods i've found on here, including https://timonweb.com/tutorials/fixing-certificate_verify_failed-error-when-trying-requests_html-out-on-mac/

but nothing seems to work. I'm running Raspbian Linux with Python 3

The command being run

```
python3 Script.py --endpoint "aws endpoint" --rootCA /etc/ssl/certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem --cert /greengrass/certs/RPI-certificate.pem.crt --key /greengrass/certs/RPI-private.pem.key --thingName RaspberryPi --clientId RaspberryPi
```

Does anyone have any other recommendations?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51925384/712526) is related; having said that, the answers there did not help me. Maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this exact error in my first venture into the Pi IoT SDK today.

In my case I was using the Amazon root CA (RSA 2048) certificate (as directed by Amazon). By switching to the **VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary G5 root CA certificate** (also advertised on their website) the connection worked.

So, try using the **VeriSign Endpoints (legacy)** root certificate linked to from the AWS IoT docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html