# Python requests library not accepting asp net core dev certificates

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, kestrel

I am currently trying to make a simple get request with python to an asp net core (.NET 5) API.
The API is running on kestrel with default settings (HTTPS only, HTTP 1 and 2 allowed).

### Problem

The problem is, that my call of

```py
r = requests.get("https://localhost:5001/api/authentication", params=payload, verify='../browser_exported.cer')
```

Produces the well-known error of

> (SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

When I disabled verification via `verify=False` everything works as expected but this is not a viable solution in my case.

### What I tried so far

- Using `verify=False` which works but is not a solution
- Exporting the certificates via my browser when browsing the site as a base64 encoded .cer file (like [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57466119/4932122) and [here](https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2)) and also exporting the certificate via the `certmgr` (explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/)) although both invoke the same wizard.

  - Supplying this certificate to python via `verify='<path>'` (as seen above).
  - Copying the certificate into cacert.pem from certifi (Used the same environment to execute certifi.where() that is used to execute the request)
- Installing python-certifi-win32 but after looking at its [source code](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/blob/master/certifi_win32/wincerts.py#L22) I noticed this will only import `CA` and `ROOT` from the win cert store. (the asp net core dev certificate is a self-signed certificate not present in these stores)
- Exporting the certificate with `der` encoding. This produced the expected error: `SSLError(SSLError(136, '[X509: NO_CERTIFICATE_OR_CRL_FOUND] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4263)')))`
- Verified that python does find my certificate file when specifying it as `verify` parameter. To do this I gave it a path that points to a nonexisting file and it produced the expected error: `Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: ../nothinghere.cer`

### Additional information

- I am running Windows 10 2004 19041.804 x64
- Chrome 88.0.4324.182 (to export the certificate)
- Python 3.8.5
- Certifi 2020.12.5
- Requests 2.25.1
- I am not behind any (corporate) proxy nor have I installed any vpn
- The asp net core dev certificate is not chained

[image: certificate chain]

Comment: Is the full certificate chain in the `.cer` (or `.pem`) file? You can concatenate certificates one after another.

Comment: The asp net core dev certificate is self-signed so there should be no chain. But is there any way to verify this? This is bugging me too but I went ahead and trusted the linked SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) which implies that exporting the cert via the browser will export the chain.

Comment: My guess that the certificate has no basic constrains CA:true. See duplicate for why this is needed. If this is not the cause of the problem let me know and I will reopen the question.