# Python - Install Pymodbus over pip errors

Tags: python, pip, pymodbus

I am receivng some errors when trying to install pymodbus over pip (see below).

Does anyone have any help as to why this might be happening? This is on a work computer but I have temporary admin access to try to get this installed.

```
py -3 -m pip install pymodbus
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pymodbus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pymodbus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pymodbus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pymodbus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pymodbus/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pymodbus/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pymodbus/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymodbus (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymodbus
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
```

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276380/sslerrorsslcertverificationerror1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certifica

Comment: This is a network issue. Since you mention that this is a work computer, talk to your IT department about proxy settings you might need to get this to work

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons - I do not see how this is the same, please advise if you see something I do not. Thank you.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I did talk to IT, they said to ask here! ‍♂️

Comment: The linked question has the exact same error message, so you could try to add `--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org` to your install command

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thanks this actually worked! Missed that comment in the other thread initially; appreciate your help!