# I can't see certificate chain into pem certificate file

Tags: ssl, certificate, pem, pki

I have a certificate file called customer_pem.cert . This file has PEM format. It contains three
---BEGIN CERTIFICATE-- sections (end user certificate, CA intermediate certificate and CA certificate). I'm using Windows 10. When I make double click over the file and I go to Certification Path section, I don't see the see the complete hierarchy or certificate chain. I just see the end user certificate. I don't see the CA and CA intermediate certificates.

The question is why I can't see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has no default viewer for `.pem` files. You need to split the file in separate files with the extension `.cer`.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get the entire cert chain in .pem format with **Mozilla browser**..

- **Step1**: click on padlock icon > `Connection secure`

  [image]
- **Step2**: Click `More information`

  [image]
- **Step3**: Under `Security` tab, click `View Certificate`

  [image]
- **Step4**: Scroll down, and under `Miscellaneous`, you'll see `PEM chain`

  [image]
- **Step5**: Click that to open in any text editor and you will have the entire cert chain.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is why I can't see them?

answered by [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69538737/9665545)

To see a chain of certificate you need to do the following

### Using Keytool

**1. Download and Install Java JRE**

Download from here https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Or dowload Open JDK instead https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/

select OS and Arch according to your system.

**2. Make sure your Java/OpenJDK bin Directory registered in PATH Environment Variable**

I don't know how installation behave, just make sure `%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre#.#.#_###\bin\` or `%ProgramFiles%\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-#.#.#.##-hotspot\` is in your PATH Environment Variable. Add if it isn't there.

Follow [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) tutorial if you're not familiar to edit an Environment Variable.

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41379378/9665545) if you want to do it from cmd shell.

**3. Use Keytool to show your certificate chain**

Keytool come with Java JRE and OpenJDK JRE, that's why we do the 1st step.

Open CMD, and execute the following:

```
keytool -printcert -file "path-to-pem/chain-of-cert.pem" -v
```

### Using OpenSSL

**1. Download and or Extract/Install Pre-built OpenSSL**

Download from [here](http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/ICS_Download#Download_OpenSSL_Binaries_.28required_for_SSL-enabled_components.29) (portable zip file)

Or download from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) (installer exe/msi file, the lite version should be fine)

Choose according to your system OS and Arch

**2. Make sure your OpenSSL directory is in your PATH Environment Variable**

Just like step 2 of Keytool Method, I don't know how installation behave, just make sure the directory where openssl.exe placed is in your PATH Environment Variable. Add if it isn't there.

Follow [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) tutorial if you're not familiar to edit an Environment Variable.

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41379378/9665545) if you want to do it from cmd shell.

**3. Use OpenSSL to show your certificate chain**

Open CMD, and execute the following:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile "path-to-pem/chain-of-cert.pem" | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout
```

OR

```
openssl storeutl -noout -text -certs "path-to-pem/chain-of-cert.pem"
```