# Getting error message after trying to load dataset from seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

Getting error message after trying to load dataset from seaborn. The code is done in idle.

Code:

```
import seaborn as sns

planets = sns.load_dataset('planets')
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate , it might be a possible duplicate of your question.

Comment: After  `pip install seaborn` I got the dataset loaded correctly on `windows 10`!!

Comment: Try running this `pip install --upgrade certifi`
[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python)