# Python requests: SSL certificate error (Max retries exceeded)

Tags: python, ssl

The code I am trying to use is something like

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

That did work perfectly fine until a few weeks ago. Now I get an error somewhat like this:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/folders/... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

It doesn't really matter what url I'm trying to request.

I know that similar questions have been asked on here. But usually the answer is to just add "verify=False" while doing the request. While that does work, I don't really want to add that every time I am using an old code or some code of my colleagues. Does anybody have an idea how to fix that? I read somewhere that it might have to do with setting date and time on my computer but I didn't change anything there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python has several answers that do not recommend `verify=False` (which, indeed, is a bad idea). What is the difference between your question and that one?

Comment: *"That did work perfectly fine until a few weeks ago."* - it might have been that the server certificate was improperly change and is now missing an intermediate certificate. It might also be that the domain is now reachable by IPv6 but the certificate was not properly setup for IPv6. And other things might be the cause. In order to fix it properly you need to know the reason why it fails, i.e. no specific recommendations can be given except for pointing out to similar problems. A good start is  to check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)