# seaborn.load_dataset results in URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, seaborn, nsurlerrordomain, timeouterror

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

I am trying to load dataset using seaborn, which results in the follow `URLError`:

```
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py:1282, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1281 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1282 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)



File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py:241, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    224 """
    225 Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.
    226 
   (...)
    237 data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.
    238 """
    239 url_type, path = _splittype(url)
--> 241 with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    242     headers = fp.info()
    244     # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://
    245     # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.



URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

I tried changing the internet connection and also tried unchecking the proxy server in LAN settings

Answer (score 1):

- The error 10060 means you cannot connect to the remote place. There might be several reasons for such an error:

  - See [Unable to get local issuer certificate when using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python) for problems with certificates.
  - It might be because of the network's problems or your setting issues, such as proxy settings. To solve this issue, check [How to resolve URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060).
  - Some non-standard OSs, like `ChromeOS Flex`, may not work, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76338177/7758804).
  - Make sure you're not behind a VPN.
  - That said, there isn't much we can do to resolve this type of issue.
- Try downloading the data with an alternate method

  - directly with `pandas`
  - with `requests` and then load into `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv')
```

```py
import requests
import io

t = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv').text

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the data cached path using

```
sns.get_data_home()
```

which returns something like - `'C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\seaborn\\seaborn\\Cache'`

Then download a copy of the dataset from `"https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data"` to the cached path. It should resolve the problem.

This method resolved `ConnectionResetError`

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be an issue with my ISP where it is not able to reach host https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ , specific to Jio ISP in India.

Following are the steps you can follow to verify if you are facing this error due to the same issue :-

1. Verify whether you are connected, and that connection to git hub is successful
   `PS> ssh -T git@github.com`
   A success message would be something like :
   `Hi RadhaRamanJha! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
2. [Seaborn.load_dataset](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html) documentation has information that seaborn is loading the datasets from the following github link "https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data" e.g. [dataset diamonds.csv](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/diamonds.csv) ,
   whose [raw file is downloaded by seaborn](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/utils.py#L24) from [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/diamonds.csv) [during execution of seaborn.load_dataset](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/utils.py#L590)
3. While I was able to see this code file on github.com, I was not able to open or download the raw file of any file from the dataset.
   Checked whether my system is able to establish connection to raw.githubusercontent.com . It was failing.

```
PS> ping raw.githubusercontent.com

Pinging raw.githubusercontent.com [2405:200:1607:2820:41::36] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 2405:200:1607:2820:41::36:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

4. [Searching around](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42655) I found that my ISP 'JIO Internet' had this specific issue of not able to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com .
   Switched to network of a different ISP ( Airtel Hotspot ) , and now I could ping raw.githubusercontent.com from my new ISP , and the raw file was accessible - after which seaborn also was able to download the file, and the call `seaborn.load_dataset` in my code succeeded.