# How can I resolve the 'connection refused' error in seaborn's sns.load_dataset() function?

Tags: python, seaborn, google-chrome-os, connection-refused

[image: Here's the error- URLError : <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>]

While searching for this issue, I found this-

Connectionrefusederror: [errno 111] connection refused is an error message that the Python “socket()” function will show when it cannot connect to the server due to an error or setting from your client or the server.

But I don't know how to solve this. I am using ChromeOS Flex as my OS and I have enabled Linux Development Environment. My internet connection is stable. I also uninstalled/installed seaborn too but it's still the same. I am trying to work with seaborn datasets but am not able to. Please suggest something.

Location: Sambalpur,Odisha,India.

#### Note:

As noted in the comments, `ChromeOS Flex` seems to be the issue. Same code works for the OP on a Windows system.

Comment: Are you on a vpn or behind a firewall? The datasets are located in github at https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data. Can you go to that site? Can you download something with [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), as a test?

Comment: Does something like `df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/raw/titanic.csv')` work?

Comment: @JohanC No. It keeps loading and says connection timed out. The internet connection is stable though.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes I am able to access the website and am able to scrape with requests too.

Comment: What type of system? Linux Mac Windows. What version, etc? If you don’t mind telling us, what’s your geographic location?

Comment: If you have access to Google Colab, does that work?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes. It's working in google collab. I had installed anaconda distribution and was working with jupyter notebook.

Comment: Maybe it's a `ChromeOS Flex` issue, but I have no way to test that.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney It seems so because i just tried the same thing with a windows laptop and it is working. Thanks for the help.