# getting time out error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter-lab

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/feI7x.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpTul.png)

Trying to use the inbuild dataset in seaborn but getting timeout error all the time. Install the Jupyter Notebook  Using Pip command. Attempted all the things include Reinstall the Jupyter, python.

```
ipykernel                 6.27.1
ipython                   8.18.1
isoduration               20.11.0
jsonpointer               2.4
jsonschema                4.20.0
jsonschema-specifications 2023.11.2
jupyter_client            8.6.0
jupyter_core              5.5.1
jupyter-events            0.9.0
jupyter-lsp               2.2.1
jupyter_server            2.12.1
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.0
jupyterlab                4.0.9
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0
jupyterlab_server         2.25.2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: at least copy your traceback as text, please

Comment: The problem is usually a temporary network issue or a firewall blocking something. You can usually get around this specific issue. I'll point you to some help for that in a separate comment; however, the last two comments have pointed out serious deficiencies in your looking into this issue and posting here about it. For example, the tile is horrible and you shouldn't be pasting code. And it seems you did no research. All these are things you are guided to do here in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77589999/8508004) from earlier in the month for some guidance on what is going on and/or how to work around it. You'll see this was duplicated from an already answered post. Yours is the same. The original pointed to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74795336/8508004) is a better example of how to ask good questions here. Compare it to yours and the better than your post, but still poor post on this topic [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77589999/8508004).

Comment: Be careful doing things that may cause you even more headaches before you research an issue like this. I'm referring to this statement "Attempted all the things include Reinstall the Jupyter, python." If you had a fairly up to date version of Jupyter and things had been working for the most part then looking into other examples getting this error, you hopefully would have seen that was unnecessary. And if you do something like that without cleaning out your system first, you can cause your environment to become more messed up than when you first encountered that issue. One way to....

Comment: <continued> is to use temporary sessions on a remote computer to see if the issue your system or network without needing to reinstall like you did. For example, you can get a temporary Jupyter session in your browser without logging in by clicking on several of the  '`launch binder`' badges [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/sample_repos.html). I in particular often use the one you get from launching from https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements .  Or if in that remote session, you can just work there and download your work frequently back to your local system.