# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED docusign python sdk

Tags: python, ssl, jwt, docusign-sdk

When trying to get jwt token:

```
client = docusign_esign.ApiClient()
client.request_jwt_application_token(
private_key_bytes=key['Body'].read(),
client_id=os.environ['DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY'],
oauth_host_name='account.docusign.com',
expires_in=36000
)
```

I receive following error

`urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='account.docusign.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))`

I am mac user and code is running on conda env with python 3.10.

I tried following solutions:
[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)
[Unable to get local issuer certificate when using requests in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925384/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-using-requests-in-python)