# cURL queries work, but python-request fails

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-requests

## Summary

We are using a custom CA in our enviroment. I have imported the CA certificates in the trust store by downloading the Base64 certs and updating the trust store using `update-ca-certificates`.

I am able to run cURL queries to my REST API, however the request library fails with an SSL error when running the same.

## What I have tried

I have tried specifying the root ca certificate file path to the library, but got the same error. How do I troubleshoot this issue? Setting verify to false is not an option.

## Code Run

### Works

curl -X GET https://api.me.com/admin/ -H 'Authorization: Token 4ae5'

### Doesn't work

requests.get('https://api.me.com/admin/', headers={'Authorization': 'Token 4ae5'}, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/root.pem')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 325, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 377, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 988, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 630, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 588, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

Comment: `requests.get(..., verify='/etc/ssl/certs/root.pem')` - are you sure you are using the correct path? Given your description of using `update-ca-certificates` I guess you are using Debian or similar (i.e. Ubuntu). In this case the relevant path should be `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Comment: God, this is embarrassing. You are absolutely right, I had to use the bundled certificate. I kept on trying the absolute paths i specified in the /etc/ca-certificates.conf and kept getting errors! :D

Please post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `... requests.get(..., verify='/etc/ssl/certs/root.pem')`

Given your description of using `update-ca-certificates` it looks like you are using Debian or similar (i.e. Ubuntu). In this case the relevant path should be `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Python `Requests` uses certificates from the [`python-certifi` package.](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/), not those of the underlying operating system.

`certifi` includes all CA certificates from Mozilla, and it is also relatively straightforward to add missing certificates to it.

See this post for details on adding certificates to `certifi`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111417/516699

The good thing is also that you do not tweak the SSL of the underlying system, just that of the Python environment your are working in.